# how to java HSSFSheet (POI API ) transfer data to

Tags: java, excel, templates, intellij-idea, structured-data

assume we have 1000000 row of student info need to move into excel due to some indexout of bound problem that i cannot do split sheets very clear so can some one write a presudo code to describe the details for me please?
the data may like this following below:
e.g. [student-number name age address] ... each row should be look like this and with the maximum length of row which is 0-65535 per sheet

my answer may like

for loop each data
e.g. for(i < data) {

```
for(i < data) {
   //create a sheet
   // define the initial row
   // add data 
   // change row when finish
}
but there is a question when we have a page was full then how to make next data will consecutively connect to a new sheet ?
like we have running over 65535 data then we need to put 65536th data into next sheet first row and first column
am i make myself clear?
```

Answer (score 0):

my answer may like

for loop each data
e.g. for(i < data) {

```
for(i < data) {
   //create a sheet
   // define the initial row
   // add data 
   // change row when finish
}
but there is a question when we have a page was full then how to make next data will consecutively connect to a new sheet ?
like we have running over 65535 data then we need to put 65536th data into next sheet first row and first column
am i make myself clear?
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).